# how do I remove oringal background color from animation

Tags: ios, swift

How do I make my animation only use colors in the “colors” array and not use oringal white background as it’s first key frame? Please help

Any way to skip/delete/ the first key frame which is white.

```
var color1 = UIColor.purple
var color2 = UIColor.blue
var color3 = UIColor.green
var color4 = UIColor.yellow
var color5 = UIColor.orange


extension UIViewController {


    func viewDidLoad(){
    

    let colors = [color1, color2, color3, color4, color5]
    
    
    
    
    
        let totalDuration = 5.0
   
    let relDuration: CGFloat = 1.0 / CGFloat(colors.count)
   
   var relStartTime: TimeInterval = 0.0
   
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: totalDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .allowUserInteraction, .autoreverse, .calculationModeCubicPaced], animations: {
       colors.forEach { c in
           UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: relStartTime, relativeDuration: relDuration, animations: {
               self.view.backgroundColor = c
           })
           relStartTime += relDuration
   }}
                           
   )


    }

}
```

[image: Speed up version of animation showing the pause on the background]

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want / expect. Consider: the view background *is* white, so the *first* keyframe of your animation animates *from* that white color to `color1`, which is purple. Moreover, you have `.autoreverse`, so the *last* keyframe is the opposite of that, which means we animate *from* purple to white. Then we start over again, animating from white to purple.

Therefore, during that last frame of the first cycle followed by the first frame of the second cycle, the view background is going to spend, roughly, the last third of the last frame and first third of the first frame of the next cycle, being white.

In other words, there is no "pause". Your animation *is* "continuous". There is a noticeable white period at the end of each cycle and the start of the next cycle, because that is what you asked for as part of the animation you configured. The animation goes

```
white
purple
blue
green
yellow
orange [and now reverse]
yellow
green
blue
purple
white
white [and now begin again]
purple
...
```

If you didn't want to see white for that long, you should not have involved white at the start and end of the animation. It's easy to arrange that, but you need to be more specific in your own mind, and in the question, about what you want the animation to be. When you have decided what the animation should be, you can write that animation, or if you can't, you can ask about it. But at the moment you are simply getting the animation you asked for and you don't seem to have a clear vision of what animation you actually want.

Comment: Ah ok thank you so much for explaining. I understand now but not really how to change it. How would I skip over white key frame to just use ones in “color” Array.

Comment: I think the question is how you want to get from the initial white state to the initial purple. You can "jump" to it, but that is probably not what you want. So what you really want, I suspect, is _two_ animations: first we animate quickly from white to purple, and _then_ we start your cycle animation. But keep in mind that if you use an autoreverse animation, _some_ color is going to last longer than the others, because it will occupy the end of the first cycle and start of the next, just like your white is doing now.

Comment: Basically what you should do is forget all these tricks like autoreverse and repeat, and just write down each color transition, in order, and how long you want it to take, for the _entire_ course of the animation. Then construct an animation that gives you that. As I said in my answer, it's possible to help you, but first you have to decide what you actually want. Right now, you are just writing some code and seeing what animation you get; do the opposite: decide _first_ what animation you want, and then write it.